# NLog, how to execute code on logging ERROR and higher?

Tags: c#, nlog

I'm quite new to NLog and I wanted to execute some code when logs are done.

Basically, I got a `RichTextBoxTarget`. The `RichTextBox` is hidden by default. I want to display it when a Error log or higher is done.

How could I do this, if it's possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you would like to have 2 targets listening for events:

- RichTextBox-Target for capturing all events in the error-window.
- MethodCall-Target for reacting to error-events and show the error-window.

So the trick is just to setup the two targets:

```
<nlog>
    <targets>
        <target name="richtext" xsi:type="RichTextBox" />
        <target name="showrichtext" xsi:type="MethodCall" className="SomeNamespace.MyClass, MyAssembly" methodName="LogMethod" />
    </targets>

    <rules>
        <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="richtext" />
        <logger name="*" minlevel="Error" writeTo="showrichtext" />
    </rules>
</nlog>
```

And implement a suitable static method for the MethodCall-Target to call.

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/MethodCall-target

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/RichTextBox-target

Comment: Yes. That's it. Thank you. It suits perfectly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

What is the purpose of this `RichTextBox` exactly?

If you want to show errors on input error then the `ErrorProvider` is better for that.

If you want to capture Error Logging also into this RTB as well as to say file, then you can write your own target, register it, and then it can process the events.

See:
https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Extending-NLog

Comment: I discovered about the `MethodCall` target. I think it will fit my needs if I use it to execute a method to show the RTB. Now I need to get how it works...